# How to set path value in jmeter based on certain value

Tags: netbeans, jmeter

I have 20 endpoints that need to be load tested using the JMeter. I have created a CSV file that contains the server name and path value and now I want to read this CSV file in JMeter and set the value of path and server name based on API name.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose this or that endpoint basing on the API Name - take a look at [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller), it executes one of its children depending on the "Switch value" which can be a variable.

You can combine "ServerName" and "Path" into one line and put everything into [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables)